# Complex filter with LexikFormFilterBundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do a complex filter in symfony2 with this [bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle), so   according with the following entities

The main entity in the filter form:

```php
<?php

...

/**
 * LecturaActivo
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LecturaActivo
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $descripcion;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date", nullable = true)
     */
    private $fecha;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hora", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hora;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OperadorActivos", inversedBy="lecturas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operador_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $operador;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Activo", inversedBy="lecturas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="activo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $activo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lista", inversedBy="lecturas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lista_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $lista;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\controlid\Bundle\ActivosBundle\Entity\Categoria", inversedBy="lecturas")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoria_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * nullable = true
    */
    protected $categoria;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="posX", type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $posX;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="posY", type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $posY;
    #getters and setters...
}
```

This is `Operadores`  Entity:

```
<?php

namespace controlid\Bundle\ActivosBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * OperadorActivos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OperadorActivos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombres", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombres;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pin", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pin;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activo", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $activo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\controlid\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Usuario", inversedBy="operadoresActivos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $cliente;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LecturaActivo", mappedBy="operador",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $lecturas;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\controlid\Bundle\ActivosBundle\Entity\Lista", inversedBy="operadores", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lista_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * nullable = true
     */
    protected $lista;
    
   #getters and setters
}
```

This is the filterType:

```php
<?php

...

class LecturaActivoFilterType extends AbstractType
{


    function __construct($listas, $operadores, $activos, $categorias)
    {
        $this->choicesListas = array(  );
        foreach ($listas as $lista) {
            if(count($lista->getOperadores()) != 0 && count($lista->getActivos())!=0){
                array_push($this->choicesListas, $lista);
            }
        }
        $this->choicesActivos = $activos;
        $this->choicesOperadores =$operadores;
        $this->choicesCategorias =$categorias;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('lista', 'filter_entity', array(
                'class'   =>'controlidActivosBundle:Lista',
                'choices'  =>$this->choicesListas,

                ))
            ->add('operador', 'filter_entity', array('class'=>'controlidActivosBundle:OperadorActivos', 'choices'=>$this->choicesOperadores))
            ->add('categoria', 'filter_entity', array('class'=>'controlidActivosBundle:Categoria', 'choices'=>$this->choicesCategorias))
            ->add('activo', 'filter_entity', array('class'=>'controlidActivosBundle:Activo', 'choices'=>$this->choicesActivos))
            ->add('fecha', 'filter_date_range', array(
                'left_date_options' => array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'date form-box'),
                ),
                'right_date_options' => array(
                   'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'date form-box'),
                ),
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'controlid_activo_filer';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'validation_groups' => array('filtering') // avoid NotBlank() constraint-related message
        ));
    }
}
```

According with the  above entities I wanna do a filter in which I could do a filter in which the `LecturaActivo->operador`  is equal to some `operadorParameter` and  where the `operador->cliente` is a some `clienteParameter` by default, but I don't know how.